# How to calculate X Y coordinates of image when window resize?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am writing a code for putting small image on HTML canvas. Also generate click event on that image. Image have height(50), width(50), X-Y coordinates(250, 150) and canvas also have height(480), width(720).

So when I click on image then getting alert("You clicked on image"). But generating alert on wrong place also when I resize window to small then also alert message generate on wrong place.

I want to generate alert message on only click on image. And if I resize window(small) then also alert message should be generated on only click on image.
    
Check fiddle-
    [enter link description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/u84p9qn1/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the canvas element and canvas bitmap has different sizes, you need to use a factor to scale the mouse position to fit relative in the bitmap. This can be done dividing the bitmap size on the element size.

**[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/u84p9qn1/2/)**

```
$("#myCanvas").click(function (event) {

    // get size of element and divide bitmap size on it
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scaleX = this.width  / rect.width;
    var scaleY = this.height / rect.height;

    // scale position: (first adjust, then scale)
    var mouseX = Math.round((event.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX);
    var mouseY = Math.round((event.clientY - rect.top ) * scaleY);

    var x = 250;
    var y = 150;
    var w = 50;
    var h = 50;

    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + w && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + h) {
        alert("You clicked on image");
    }
}
```